# Find if the a cell within the first column has been selected?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Hello I'm using Visual Basic 2010,

I have a datagridview and I want a listbox to show if a cell within the first column has been selected so I need something like

IF 'a cell in the first column has been selected' then
listbox1.show
end if

Any help would be appreciated thanks,

Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tie this code to your DataGridView's CellClick event

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) { listBox1.Visible = true; }
        else { listBox1.Visible = false; }
    }
```